# Wordpress add_option query returning blank parameter

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, loops, wordpress-theming

I have some code that shows a Wordpress feature image.
If a feature image has not been set, it should show a default image.
For some reason, my code is returning a blank value for the URL parameter if no featured image is found.

So the output code is showing as...

background-image: url()

instead of

background-image: url(http://website/image.jpg)

Any help appreciated.

```
<?php 
add_option( 'default_image', 'http://website/image.jpg', '', 'yes' );    
if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
} else {
    $image = get_option( 'default_image' );
}
?>
<div class="news-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image[0]; ?>);">
```

Comment: Have you tried a var_dump() on your $image var? What does it output?
And is your option in the database?
Oh and by the way, `get_option()` return a mixed value, but in your case you don't have to do `$image[0]`, `$image` would be enough

Comment: the image has to be in the database? i can't use a regular url or link to an image in a folder? and if I remove the [0] it doesn't work.

Comment: I mean, your option 'default_image' should appear in your database on the 'options' table

Comment: can you explain this please? I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: If you can access on your website's database, take a look on the table 'xxx_options', and look if you can find the value 'default_image', in the column 'option_name' (xxx stands for your db prefix): AND can you please give us the output of `<?php var_dump($image); ?>` ?

Comment: yes i can see the option in the database. the var_dump returns NULL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82999/discussion-between-dfayet-and-lowercase).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion it appears that 
`if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) )`
return true even if $post had no thumbnail.

This issue seems to have already appeared to [someone](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/has_post_thumbnail-returns-true-on-every-post).

In our case this subject was solved with the following code :

```
<?php 
    add_option( 'default_image', 'http://website/image.jpg', '', 'yes' );

    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 

    if ( !$image ){
        $image[0] = get_option( 'default_image' ); 
    } 
?>
<div class="news-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image[0]; ?>);">
```

Hope it may help you all

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because your image variable is a string when returned from the database. You can change

```
$image = get_option( 'default_image' );
```

to

```
$image[0] = get_option( 'default_image' );
```

and it should work.

Comment: still returns blank url unfortunately.